# Better way to check a list for specific elements - python

Tags: python, if-statement, try-except

I am using `try/except` blocks as a substitute for `if/elif` that has a bunch of `and`s. I am looking into a list and replacing some elements if it has x and x and x, etc. In my project, I have to check for upwards of 6 things which drew me to using the `try/except` with `.index()` which will throw an error if the element isn not present.

An analogy looks like this:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange']

try:
    red_index = colors.index('red')
    blue_index = colors.index('blue')
    colors[red_index] = 'pink'
    colors[blue_index] = 'light blue'
except ValueError:
    pass
try:
    yellow_index = colors.index('yellow')
    purple_index = colors.index('purple')
    colors[yellow_index] = 'amarillo'
    colors[purple_index] = 'lavender'
except ValueError:
    pass
```

So if the `colors` array doesn't contain `'purple'` as well as `'yellow'`, I don't want the array to change.

I am a bit wary of this approach because it seems like abuse of `try/except`. But it is much shorter than the alternative because I would have to grab the elements' `index` anyway, so I would like to know if there are blatant problems with this or if this is crazy enough that other developers would hate me for it.

Comment: `len(set(colors) & set("purple yellow".split())) == 2`

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's much 'shorter'? Lines of code or time efficiency?

Comment: Using `if ('red' in colors and 'blue' in colors):` instead of `try:` should make all the difference you need.

Comment: @lluvatar14 There are now several answers to your question. Would you please select one as your preferred solution (by clicking the checkmark to the left of it) so that your question may be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not crazy; try/except is pretty pythonic - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132718/best-way-to-handle-list-indexmight-not-exist-in-python) for more discussion.

The other way you could do this is:

```
if 'red' in colours and 'blue' in colours:
    colour[colours.index('red')] = 'pink'
    # etc
```

Advantages over try/except:

1. Fewer lines of code if you're into that
2. Much more readable - any future reader would immediately know what you mean

Disadvantages over try/except:

1. Slower (albeit by a totally negligible amount) since `contains` will do its own search for the element.

Unless you're doing something that requires this to be extremely time efficient, I'd favour readability. However, the try/except isn't unforgivable if you have other reasons for doing it.

Comment: Thanks @alksdjg, this answer is most useful to me. I think readability here is a must but I will stick with `try/except` to avoid the `and`s.

Comment: Thanks very much, although to be clear, I'm saying the try/except is *less* readable than the if statement.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm dumb, you did say that. Still though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). We'll use [**`issuperset`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset), [**`difference_update`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference_update), and [**`update`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.update), abbreviated to `>=`, `-=`, and `|=`, respectively:

```
colors = {'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange'}

if colors >= {'red', 'blue'}:
    colors -= {'red', 'blue'}
    colors |= {'pink', 'light blue'}
elif colors >= {'yellow', 'purple'}:
    colors -= {'yellow', 'purple'}
    colors |= {'amarillo', 'lavender'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

You'll probably want to build a function using map(), like so:

```
def replace(sequence, replaceDict):
    for seekVal in replaceDict.keys():
        if seekVal not in sequence:
            return sequence #Not modified, as seek not found.
    replaceFunc = lambda item: replaceVal if item==seekVal else item
    for seekVal in replaceDict:
        replaceVal = replaceDict[seekVal]
        sequence = map(replaceFunc, sequence)
    return sequence
```

Then just run:

```
colors = replace(colors, {'red' : 'pink', 'blue' : 'light blue'})
```

Comment: Mm, misunderstood the question. Multiple requirements are necessary before change. Gimme a minute, I'll rewrite the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close, but there are some useful built in functions that will help:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange']

if ('red' in colors and 'blue' in colors):
    red_index = colors.index('red')
    blue_index = colors.index('blue')
    colors[red_index] = 'pink'
    colors[blue_index] = 'light blue'

if ('yellow' in colors and 'purple' in colors):
    yellow_index = colors.index('yellow')
    purple_index = colors.index('purple')
    colors[yellow_index] = 'amarillo'
    colors[purple_index] = 'lavender'
```

This creates logical gates (that both colors must be present) so that it will only execute when you want it to.

It's a very small change, but I think it will handle your error cases in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually go in an easier and far more shorter way using `dict` and list comprehension like this:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange']

# First define you replaces
replaces = {
    'red': 'ping',
    'blue': 'light blue',
    'yellow': 'amarillo',
    'purple': 'lavender'
}

# Then define the replacing function
def replace(key, replaces):
    return replaces.get(key) or key

# And then replace all the intended element
colors = [replace(el, replaces) for el in colors]
```

So what this will do, is for each element, it will look it up in the dict, if it is in the dict (i.e. intended to be replaced), then it will return the appropriate replacement, otherwise, it will return the original value.

So then introducing your conditions, you could go like this:

```
if 'purple' in colors and 'red' in colors:
    colors = [replace(el, {
            'yellow': 'amarillo',
            'purple': 'lavender'
        }) for el in colors]

...
```

And the same for any other conditions.